# Python quick trick to arrange list

Tags: python, django

again. 
I have this:

```
[
 [{'location': u'Austria',      u'number': 33},
 {'location':  u'Albania',      u'number': 29},
 {'location':  u'Afghanistan',  u'number': 666}],

 [{'location': u'Austria',      u'items': 6},
 {'location':  u'Albania',      u'items':  1},
 {'location':  u'Afghanistan'}, u'items':  0],

 [{'location': u'Austria',      u'loss': 1.0},
 {'location':  u'Albania',      u'loss': 2.0},
 {'location':  u'Afghanistan',  u'loss': 6.6}]
]
```

And I've tried generate list like this:

```
[
 [u'Austria',     33,  6, 1.00], 
 [u'Albania',     29,  1, 2.00], 
 [u'Afghanistan', 666, 0, 6.60]
]
```

I've tried this:

```
country = [i['location'] for i in data[0]]
number =  [i['number'] for i in data[0]]
items =   [i['items'] for i in data[1]]
loss =    [i['loss'] for i in data[2]]
```

then I zip this:

```
for i in range(0,len(country)):
        l.append([name[i], number[i], items[i], loss[i]])
```

And its work, but:
1) its ugly (for me)
2) its not 'one-size-fits-all'

In other time I may have only:

```
[
 [{'location': u'Austria',      u'number': 33},
 {'location':  u'Albania',      u'number': 29},
 {'location':  u'Afghanistan',  u'number': 666}],

 [{'location': u'Austria',      u'loss': 1.0},
 {'location':  u'Albania',      u'loss': 2.0},
 {'location':  u'Afghanistan',  u'loss': 6.6}]
]
```

And my code will fail (out of index), other time I may have more list in list, etc.
How do this fine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I'd transpose it so that all Australia are together:

```
data_t = zip(*data)
```

Then I'd accumulate the rows by pulling off the first non-`'location'` key in the sub-dict (since that seems to be the field you're looking for).

```
rows = []
for country_dat in data_t:
    country = country_dat[0]['location']
    row = [country]
    rows.append(row)
    for dct in country_dat:
        key = next(k for k in dct if k != 'location')
        row.append(dct[key])
```

Comment: Great, answer! I am just wondering why you have `rows = []` in there? It seems you don't need that.

Comment: @JoeR -- I need to have the rows around so that I can append each new row as I go along (See the 5th line in the second block of code).

Comment: Oh yes, my bad! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
from collections import OrderedDict

od=OrderedDict()
for dl in data:
  for d in dl:    
    loc = d['location']
    od.setdefault(loc,{}).update(**d)

for k in od: print od[k]

{u'loss': 1.0, 'location': u'Austria', u'number': 33}
{u'loss': 2.0, 'location': u'Albania', u'number': 29} 
{u'loss': 6.6, 'location': u'Afghanistan', u'number': 666}
```

It will accumulate any set of directory keys into a single directory, and preserve the original ordering of locations.

From here if you want a list-of-lists with any fields in any order:

```
fields=['location', 'loss', 'number'] 
lofl = [[ oo[k][x] for x in fields] for k in oo ]

>>> lofl
[[u'Austria', 1.0, 33], [u'Albania', 2.0, 29], [u'Afghanistan', 6.6, 666]]
```